# Maven javadoc plugin: is it possible to show private selectively for certain packages

Tags: maven, maven-javadoc-plugin

I am interested in showing `private` members in javadoc for only certain packages. For the all other packages only show `public` and `protected` members in javadoc. The `show` tag is for configuration, but not for the group.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Apache Maven Javadoc Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/) it uses [javadoc - The Java API Documentation Generator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#public). I'm not aware of an option in `javadoc` for changing access modifiers for indivdual packages with the standard doclet. You could write your [own doclet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html), of course.

I can also imagine the following hack:

- create a "main" JavaDoc with a certain access modifier and assign the desired packages
- create a second JavaDoc with a different access modifier and assign the desired packages
- create a third ...

  Now the hacker's part:
- merge the second JavaDocs' `allclasses-[frame|noframe].html` (All Classes) into *main's* `allclasses-[frame|noframe].html`
- merge the second JavaDocs' `overview-frame.html` (Packages) into *main's* `overview-frame.html`
- merge the third ...
- merge the third ...